# Dataset Time Windowing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, sliding-window

I have a Dataset under this form

[image: DATASET Form]

I want to split the data set by making a windowing which includes the lines that happen every 2 minutes, then i m going to include the result in another data set which will be under this form
[image: Result]

i'm asking if anyone can offer me a hand to speed up my work?

Comment: what if you ha `04:07:30, 04:09:10, 04:10:00` note that the frst is within 2 minutes of the 2nd and the 2nd is within 2 minutes of the last so how would you group them?

Comment: fortunately i don't have this case in my data set, i just want to group them within the same array depending on the time difference,which means i want to group the ones that happen every two minutes. and i want the result to be under this form : [[1,3,5][2,2][13,3][9,1]]

Comment: What is the difference between the two data frames? How time changes from `04:07:04` to `04:07:00`? Do you want rounding or interpolation or what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a random dataframe, df:

```
df:
                     Content
Date                        
2021-12-04 04:07:04        6
2021-12-04 04:07:20        1
2021-12-04 04:08:04        4
2021-12-04 04:09:04       12
2021-12-04 04:12:04        4
2021-12-04 04:15:04        8
2021-12-04 04:15:04       10
2021-12-04 04:16:04        4
2021-12-04 04:17:04        6
2021-12-04 04:17:24        3
```

Now, I will use `pd.Grouper` for '2Min' frequency and `apply(list)`

```
df_out= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Min'))['Content'].apply(list).
```

df_out:

```
Date
2021-12-04 04:06:00       [6, 1]
2021-12-04 04:08:00      [4, 12]
2021-12-04 04:10:00           []
2021-12-04 04:12:00          [4]
2021-12-04 04:14:00      [8, 10]
2021-12-04 04:16:00    [4, 6, 3]
```

if you want the 2nd column as a list then use `.tolist()`:

```
list=df_out.tolist()
list:
[[6, 1], [4, 12], [], [4], [8, 10], [4, 6, 3]]
```

to get each element use `df_out[i]` # i=0,1,2, etc
if you want to convert it into a data frame then use `pd.DataFrame(df_out)`

Remember if you are reading the text file from a csv or whatever file you will have to convert your df index to datetime index using:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Entire code for a test csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'D:\python\test.txt', sep=',').set_index('Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df_out= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Min'))['Content'].apply(list)
```

If you don't know how to create a sample df, here I put another example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
# create an array of 10 dates starting at '2021-12-04', one per minute 
rng = pd.date_range('2021-12-04 04:07:04', periods=10, freq='T')
df_random = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Content': np.random.randint(1,13,10) }).set_index('Date') 

df_random_out= df_random.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Min'))['Content'].apply(list)

 df_random:
                     Content
Date                        
2021-12-04 04:07:04        6
2021-12-04 04:08:04        1
2021-12-04 04:09:04        4
2021-12-04 04:10:04       12
2021-12-04 04:11:04        4
2021-12-04 04:12:04        8
2021-12-04 04:13:04       10
2021-12-04 04:14:04        4
2021-12-04 04:15:04        6
2021-12-04 04:16:04        3

df_random_out:
Date
2021-12-04 04:06:00        [6]
2021-12-04 04:08:00     [1, 4]
2021-12-04 04:10:00    [12, 4]
2021-12-04 04:12:00    [8, 10]
2021-12-04 04:14:00     [4, 6]
2021-12-04 04:16:00        [3]
```

N.B: Please explain clearly what you want to do with your results so that I can answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Shuvashish Roy. Firstly, I want to thank you sincerely for your great response. It was very helpful in my research. But, I want to further ask you. My question is the following: how can I get access to the content column in the second Datset 'df_out' ? And you've my gratitude.

Comment: Check the edited answer. Pls accept the answer if it serves your purpose.

Comment: Hi, for your NB : Please explain clearly what you want to do with your results so that I can answer accordingly.    Am currently working on an application that detects anomalies/abnormalities in log files so i want to divide my data into different période to compare them to each other and detect the abnormalities

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time and I posted an answer but deleted as I realised it was different from the expected result...also took a piece of @Shuvashish - the apply(list). But anyways..this should give you the expected result:

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time',inplace=True)

df2=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2Min',origin=df.index[0].floor('Min')))['Content'].apply(list).explode())

df2[df2.Content.notna()].reset_index()
```

Shuvashish already showed the pd.Grouper - I only exploded the results and set the origin to be the first time value 'floored' to the minute - btw in your expected table ,there shouldn't be 04:50:00 time as we started binning every 2 minutes from an odd number 04:07:00